# How to use Eloquent ORM to query relationship item with where conditions?

Tags: sql, orm, laravel, eloquent

For example, I have a `User` has many `Comments`, but I would like to query the `Comment` is status 1 only. How can I do that using Eloquent ORM in Laravel? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like

```
$user->comments()->where('status', 1)->get();
```

By adding the parenthesis after comments you will receive a QueryBuilder instance instead of a Collection of results.